# Sum of complex numbers at the vertices of a regular polygon

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

[image: Question]

> If $z_1,z_2,z_3, \ldots ,z_n$ are the vertices of an $n$-sided regular polygon with $z_0$ as its centre, then find
> $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} z_r^k$$where $k \in \Bbb N, k<n$.

And my working is here:

[image: Working]

> $$z_r - z_0 = (z_1-z_0)e^{i(2\pi(r-1)/n)}$$
> $$\sum_{r=1}^n z_r^k = \left(z_0+(z_1-z_0)e^{i(2\pi(r-1)/n)}\right)^k$$

Thanking you in anticipation,
Ann

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also, please typeset your mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Doing so will help prevent your question from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience. ¶ For example, `$z_0, z_1, \ldots, z_n$` yields $z_0, z_1, \ldots, z_n$, `$\sum_{r=1}^n z_r^k$` yields $\sum_{r=1}^n z_r^k$, and `$k \in \mathbb{N}$` yields $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Image $n=4$, do you mean that $z_0=(1,0)$, $z_1=(0,1)$, $z_2=(-1,0)$ and $z_3=(0,-1)$ or can the sequence be random (like $z_0=(-1,0)$, $z_1=(0,-1)$, z_2=(0,1) and $z_3=(1,0)$)?

Comment: Hmm, as a side lemma, try to prove that if $n$ does not divide $k$, and $\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots \omega_n$ are the nth roots of unity, then $\sum_{r=1}^n \omega_{r}^k = 0$. Then apply rotation and translation to finish the problem.

Comment: Hint: consider the case of $z_0=0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\ \frac{z_1^k + z_2^k + \cdots + z_n^k}{n} = \left(\frac{z_1 + z_2 + \cdots + z_n}{n}\right)^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308415/prove-that-fracz-1k-z-2k-cdots-z-nkn-left-fracz-1-z-2)

Answer (score 1):

As recommended in the comments start with the Lemma:

$$\forall\{m:\, n\nmid m\}:\quad \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(\omega_{n,\alpha}^r\right)^m=0,\tag1$$
where $\omega_{n,\alpha}^r=e^{i\left(\alpha+\frac{2\pi}nr\right)}$

The proof is trivial:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{i\left(\alpha+\frac{2\pi}nr\right)m}=e^{i\alpha m}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{i\frac{2\pi}nrm}=e^{i\alpha m}\frac{1-e^{i(2\pi m)}}{1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}nm}}=0.
$$

Now since $z_r=z+R\omega_{n,\alpha}^r$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}z_r^k&=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(z+R\omega_{n,\alpha}^r\right)^k\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sum_{m=0}^k \binom km z^{k-m}R^{m}\left(\omega_{n,\alpha}^r\right)^m\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^k \binom km z^{k-m}R^{m}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(\omega_{n,\alpha}^r\right)^m\\
&=nz^k.
\end{aligned}
$$

The last equality holds since in view of $k<n$ only the term with $m=0$ survives according to Lemma $(1)$.